# How to open a file found with Dir?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to loop through all Excel files in a folder and copy & transpose information from sheet3 onto sheet1 on a master file.

The looping function uses a filepath and the Dir command to return the file location, but presents an error message when instructed to open the file, saying: >"Run-time Error 1004: We could not find Testfile.xls. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?"

I've included the code for how the filepath is defined and how the loop function is meant to summon the first file. When I began working on this code this morning, I was able to open files; however, after updating my Excel (MAC 2017 edition) to get access to more tools in the VBA editor, I could no longer open files using `workbooks.open`.

I tried `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)` instead of stating the file path, but the dialogue box does not open. I'm not sure if I need to revert to an earlier version of Excel or if there is an issue in my syntax that I am overlooking that can explain why my error box can tell me the name of the file but thinks it isn't in the folder.

```vb
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
    
    Dim MySource As String
    'the name for file that data will come from
    Dim Filepath As String
    
    Filepath = "/Users/Victor/Desktop/Clocks/"
    'the folder that files are located in
    MySource = Dir(Filepath)
    'define location of source files
    
    'Establish loop
    Do While Len(MySource) > 0  
        If MySource = "zzmaster.xlsx" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'process should loop through all files in the directory until it reaches the master file...
        'master file should be the last file in the folder, so loop contains all relevant files
    
        'begin loop
        Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(MySource)    <--the error generates at this step
        DoEvents
        
        'Opens source file
```

The code is being run from the zzmaster.xlsx file, which is in a folder on my desktop along with five test files. I don't have the experience with this language to recognize if the error is in the syntax, in my file management, or in my decision to update Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dir` only returns the *filename* of each file in the folder. When you try to open it, VBA is looking in the current working directory. To open a file in another location you need to use the full path:

```
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filepath + MySource)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what the issue was. It runs correctly now (right into my next error...) More debugging awaits!